# Asp core URLs in the form of sitename.com/en/Page

Tags: asp.net-core, localization, asp.net-mvc-routing, razor-pages

I'm trying to set up an asp core 3 razor pages app with language URL's in the form of `sitename.com/en/Page`.

In startup, I prefix every route template with a `{culture}` parameter using a custom `PageRouteModelConvention`. This works fine and the `RouteDataRequestCultureProvider` can read the culture out.

The main problem I have is that every link and redirect on the site now needs to add the current culture as a route parameter. I was hoping that ambient route values would keep the current culture set automatically.

My questions are:

1. Is prefixing every route with a `{culture}` parameter the correct way to do this? Is there an easier or better way?
2. If so, is there a way to keep the culture parameter set without me having to constantly add it to every link and redirect on the site?

Comment: There is an open issue on Github which asks a similar question: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/16960

Comment: a temporary but useful solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/59283426/5519026

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a generic piece of middleware which automatically redirects if the culture value isn't added in the path?

Comment: Redirects to where?
If the culture value isn't set I won't know what culture to redirect to.
If it is set then there's no problem.

Comment: You can start from a default. And with any request which does provide a culture value in the URL you can store that in a cookie for future reference.
The simplest way for a default is just to hard-code one, but you probably could use geolocation otherwise.
Alternatively, if you don't want to use a default, you could redirect first to a page where the culture is selected, and then go from there.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [URL Rewriting Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-3.0) to redirect url with culture name before the original request path.

RewriteRule.cs

```
public class RewriteRule
{ 
    public static void RedirectRequests(RewriteContext context)
    {
        //list all your supported cultures
        var cultures = new CultureInfo[]
        {
            new CultureInfo("en"),
            new CultureInfo("tr"),
            new CultureInfo("es"),
            new CultureInfo("fa"),
            new CultureInfo("hi"),
            new CultureInfo("ar-SY"),
            new CultureInfo("ar") 

        };
        var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
        var routeValues = path.Value.Split('/');

        //routeValues[1] is request culture name, if it does not exist, redirect
        if (!cultures.Any(x => x.Name.ToLower() == routeValues[1].ToLower()))
        {
            var culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
            context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect($"/{culture.Name}{path.Value }");
        }


    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {           
        app.UseRequestLocalization();
        app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().Add(RewriteRule.RedirectRequests));

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
```